# The 3d manipulator widget just isn't there. Enabling/Disabling it does nothing

Tags: modeling

Yeah, it just vanished. I pressed the "enable/disable" button, but it still doesn't show up.

Where could it possibly be? What even happened to it?

Comment: are you in 2.79 or 2.8?

Comment: I'm on 2.79b. Should I update it?

Comment: Have you enable the "Use a 3D Manipulator" button on the horizontal menu bar on the bottom of your 3D View? Or perhaps in the Preferences > Interface, enable the Manipulator option?

Comment: Yeah, nothing happens. I'll try again, though, and see if something is different after a restart.